# Python Window-positioning?

Tags: python, window, gtk, positioning, pygtk

I tried to open a new window at the same position as another window.

My Code:

```
window2.set_position(window1.get_position())
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`set_position` just sets a general hint (e.g. center the window). You need the `move` method:

`window2.move(pos_x, pos_y)`

see here: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq10.003.htp